# How this code is passing null safety in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am little confused while writing a simple class as below:

```
class NewsSource {
  final String url;
  final String name;
  final String imageUrl;
  NewsSource({required this.url, required this.name, required this.imageUrl});
  factory NewsSource.fromFireStore(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
      SnapshotOptions? options) {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    return NewsSource(
        url: data?['url'], name: data?['name'], imageUrl: data?['imageUrl']);
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toFireStore() {
    return {"url": url, "name": name, "imageUrl": imageUrl};
  }
}
```

fromFireStore function call NewsSource constructor where parameters can be null clearly but still dart is not complaining why?

PS: If I remove dynamic then it starts to complain, I guess any use of dynamic makes null check redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `dynamic`. Variables of type `dynamic` are basically not null-safe and still need to be handled accordingly.

My guess is that if we assume the map is not null then `data?['url']` would return a variable of type `dynamic` for which `null` is also a valid value. And variables of type `dynamic` are never checked for null-safety. So it doesn't even bother to complain whether the map is `null`

Comment: ok, wrapping my head around it. data is of type Map? data can be null but still no warning here.

Comment: @TarunChawla hmm yeah. You're right about that. Not sure why it doesn't complain about that.

Comment: If I remove dynamic then it starts to complain, I guess any use of dynamic makes null check redundant.

Comment: @TarunChawla my guess is that if we assume the map is not null then `data?['url']` would return a variable of type `dynamic` for which `null` is also a valid value. And variables of type `dynamic` are never checked for null-safety. So it doesn't even bother to complain whether the map is null

Comment: you could be right.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with this observation? I will accept and close with this reasoning if I did not get a better answer.

Comment: I agree with @IvoBeckers. Since `data` is composed by `dynamic` types, it could be that is not checking for null.

Answer (score 0):

This:    `Map<String, dynamic> toFireStore()` is mapping every type to a `dynamic`, which is not null-safe.

Dynamic allows non-nullable or nullable types assigned.

[Unofficial Dart Documentation](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/dynamic)

Comment: data is of type Map? data can be null but still no warning here.

Comment: Does the App correctly compile with null safety on?

Comment: I have just started work on this application so everything is up to date. SDK version is : ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0" and its building fine.

Comment: @TarunChawla Ok, but when building the app (as an apk, for example) does it say that it's building with null safety on?

Comment: Oh ok. You edited the comment.

Comment: If I remove dynamic then it starts to complain, I guess any use of dynamic makes null check redundant.